# Prevent logging sensitive data in command line history when running drush

Tags: bash, shell, drupal, drupal-7

Im trying to install Drupal using the drush command:

```
drush -y -v site-install standard --db-url=mysql://${db_user}:${db_pass}@${db_host}:${db_port}/${db_name} --account-name=${DRUPAL_ADM_USER} --account-pass=${DRUPAL_ADM_PASS} --locale=${LANG} --site-name=\"${DRUPAL_SITE_NAME}\";
```

It is using a MySQL database and I have to pass its **user** and **password** on the db-url option, but I dont want that this sensitive information appear in my console history.

I would like some help hiding this information. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So what have you tried so far ? If the answer provided is not useful please leave a comment or edit your question, otherwise you can vote and accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here 2 commands that may be useful to prevent sensitive data from being logged in your command line history :

- Use the [`read`](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/readh.html) command to prompt for the password prior to run `drush site-install`.

  ```
  # Read standard input and store it into db_pass
  # -s prevents echoing the input.
  # -p <string> outputs the string without a trailing newline before.
  read -s -p "Password : " db_pass
  ```
- You can also [`source`](https://ss64.com/bash/source.html) variables from an external file using the source or dot operator (`source` or `.`, but that means information are stored in plain text (or encrypted at best), so setting the appropriate permissions for such file should be considered first. Usage :

  ```
  # Create ~/install.conf and make it initialize db_user
  echo 'db_user=foobar' > ~/install.conf
  # Execute ~/install.conf commands in the current shell context.
  . ~/install.conf 
  # Test : outputs 'foobar'
  echo ${db_user}
  ```

A typical installation script uses both methods, in your case if all variables except *db_pass* were to be stored/initialized in `~/install.conf`, you would do something like this :

```
#!/bin/bash
. ~/install.conf
read -p 'Press [ Enter ] to begin installation'    
while [ -z "$db_pass" ] || [ "$db_pass" != "$check" ]; do
    read -s -p "Password: " db_pass && echo
    read -s -p "Confirm Password : " check && echo
done
drush -y -v site-install standard --db-url=mysql:\\//${db_user}:${db_pass}@${db_host}:${db_port}/${db_name} --account-name=${DRUPAL_ADM_USER} --account-pass=${DRUPAL_ADM_PASS} --locale=${LANG} --site-name=\"${DRUPAL_SITE_NAME}\";
```

Comment: Its a good solution, but I dont want to use an user interactive approach! Maybe I can store this password in a file and read form it, instead of aksing and waiting the user to type it.

Comment: I didnt see your second suggestion of solution. I will try the second option and give you a feedback! Thanks!

Comment: Sourcing is a good option in this case, given the fact your source file is well protected. Or you can still clean your command history after running drush, not the best option to me but still possible to remove specific commands.